# How can i route a mothod for more than one controller rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-routing

i have this in my routes.rb

```
  get "invoices/log_out" => "users#logout", :as => "log_out"
```

this seems to work only in `localhost:3000/invoices/new/log_out`
as when i am at `localhost:3000/invoices` and i click on log out i have the following error

```
No route matches [GET] "/log_out"
```

so i want to make it work in all my controllers were are five
something like `get "all_controllers/log_out" => "users#logout", :as => "log_out"`

````
   <nav class="navi_me">
          <ul>
          <li><a href="/proms/add_prom">Εισαγωγη Προμηθευτη</a></li>
          <li><a href="/proms">Προμηθευτες</a></li>
          <li><a href='/items'>Προϊόντα</a></li>
          <li><a href='/items/insert'>Εισαγωγη Προϊόν</a></li>
          <li><a href='/invoices'>Τιμολόγια</a><li> 
          <li><a href='/invoices/new'>Εισαγωγη Τιμολόγιου</a><li>
          <li><a href='/pbinvoices'>Πιστωτικά Τιμολόγια</a><li>
          <li><a href='/pbinvoices/new'>Εισαγωγη Πιστωτικου Τιμολόγιου</a><li>
          <li><a href='/census'>Απογραφες</a><li>
          <li><a href='/users/setting'>User Setting</a></li>
          <li><a href="log_out">Αποσύνδεση</a></li>
        </li>
      </ul>
      </nav>
    ```
````

```
  def logout
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to users_login_path , :notice => "Logged out!"
  end
```

Comment: Please do not edit answer in the question itself, someone took the time to help you, leave the possibility to other to read his/her answer and upvote it if that suites them too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your route:

```
get "invoices/log_out" => "users#logout", :as => "log_out"
```

When someone hits `localhost::3000/invoices/log_out` it routes the request to the `logout` method on your `UsersController`. Changing the path part to `'all_controllers/log_out'` won't change anything about the behaviour of your app other than change the text of the path. It doesn't really matter to your problem, but since logging out is a single global operation, you're probably better off with just `'/log_out'` as the route path to keep things simple.

You didn't include any snippets of your view code, but your problem is almost certainly in how you're specifying the `link_to`. The `:as => "log_out"` part of your route defines an alias for the route. Rails creates URL helpers automatically using that alias (`log_out_path` and `log_out_url`) that you can use in your views and controllers to link to that operation:

```
<%= link_to "Logout", log_out_path %>
```

Using the URL helpers ensures that your code is using right route even if you later change the actual path in `routes.rb`.